# Resolve Hostname with just the IP available

Tags: windows, cmd, ip

In my network there are plenty of devices (IPv4). Now there is a new device, I want to assign a IP, but when I assign it, there is a message: This IP is already used.

Can someone tell me, how I can get the hostname?

Already tried:
`ping -a <IP>` (Result: no resolution of hostname)
`nslookup  <IP>` (Result: Not found, "*Non-existent domain*".)
`nbtstat -A <IP`> (Result: I only get a resolution for my APIPA IP (169....))

Comment: The IP address may have assigned no hostname at all. Try *tracert <IP>* or find its MAC address with *arp -a*. You may also try to telnet it on various TCP ports to find out what  kind of device it is.

Comment: Just for interest: how does knowing the MAC help me to get the network name (hostname) of a device?

Comment: You could put MAC here http://www.macvendors.com/ to find its vendor, which might help to identify the device with duplicating IP.